# Svelte 'evaluate script' time is appearing higher compare to inferno, preact

Tags: javascript, performance, svelte, svelte-3, infernojs

I am trying to choose a library for my project which provide ***data binding and DOM management features***. Comparing multiple libraries I ended up with ***Inferno and Svelte***.

I noticed evaluate script time of **Svelte** is higher than the other libraries *(Please refer attached image)* [image].

In the sample I have rendered a 100 x 15 table (total 1500 cell). though the rendering time reduces by few milliseconds but script execution time of inferno is half of it. [image]

The time increases drastically with number of elements, Eg. for 15000 cell svelte script evaluation time is 2000ms where as inferno took 680ms.

**Svelte Code:**

```
<style>
table,td,tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<script>
import { officedatabase } from '../../../data_generator/sampleGridData/initialloaddata.js';
</script>
<table>
  {#each officedatabase as row}
    <tr>
     {#each row as cell}
      <td>{cell}</td>
     {/each}
    </tr>
  {/each}
</table>
```

**Inferno sample Code:**

```
import { Component } from 'inferno';
import { officedatabase } from './initialloaddata.js';
export default class Grid extends Component {
  state = {
    data: officedatabase
  };
  render () {
    let data = this.state.data,
      rows = data.map((row)=> {
        return (
        <tr class='row'>
          {row.map((ele)=>{
            return <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>{ele}</td>;
          })}
          </tr>
        );
      });
    return (
      <div>
        <table style='border: 1px solid black;'>
          {rows}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why this script evaluation time is high for Svelte?

Comment: I've also noticed this while populating little big data in tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that we just haven't yet done a particularly good job of optimising large lists, whereas Inferno (which is all about micro-optimisations and taking advantage of the authors' deep knowledge of how JS engines work) has. Improving it is on the TODO list!

Comment: I'd be curious if there are any hypotheses as to why this might be. One issue worth digging into further might be https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3898 ?